# How to Find Non Matches in Both Tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I came up with the query below, which finds all non matches in my 'tbl_Master_ME_List'.  What I really want to do is find non matches in BOTH tables.  Is that possible?  Of, do I need two queries to do this and one union to join them together?

```
SELECT [4 digit Code]
FROM tbl_Master_ME_List B
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM tbl_ME_List A
    WHERE A.[4 digit Code] = B.[4 digit Code])
```

I'm using SQL Server 2014.

Thanks!

Comment: you could use a full join and look for a a null in table a or table b.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select [4 digit code]
from tbl_Master_ME_List a
full outer join tbl_ME_List b on
a.[4 digit code] = b.[4 digit code]
where a.[4 digit code] is null or b.[4 digit code] is null
```